# Как я могу скачать картинку по url в папку через js или React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть input поле, и я ввожу туда url картинки(например https://pay.google.com/about/static/images/social/og_image.jpg), url любой и есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую, по ссылке(или массиве ссылок, если их больше 1) скачиваеться картинка в папку, которую я укажу. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Посли клика кнопки "Скачать" должен открыться диалог с выбором папки?

Попробуй что-нибудь из этого:

https://github.com/rndme/download

https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download

Comment: Спасибо, есть только вопрос: по некоторым ссылкам не скачивает а выкидывает в консоль.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pay.google.com/about/static/images/social/og_image.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @АнтонОнищенко Это значит что сервер на котором находятся картинки, которые Вы пытаетесь скачать, защищен политикой CORS. С этим Вы ничего не сделаете.